# Create a list of string variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

```
FILES = Y_4_X_0.log \
        Y_4_X_1.log \
        Y_4_X_2.log \
        Y_5_X_0.log \
        Y_5_X_1.log \
        Y_5_X_2.log
```

Say I want to create a variable like this. Is there a clean/readable way of doing this without using addsuffix, addprefix, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really enough information here to know what you want to do and what the requirements are (does "clean/readable" mean "without using any functions", or is there something about **addsuffix** and **addprefix** specifically that you don't like?)

Anyway, something like this will work for the small example you provide:

```
EXTS := 0 1 2
BASES := 4 5

FILES := $(foreach B,$(BASES),$(foreach E,$(EXTS),Y_$B_X_$E.log))
```